# Embedding Jess in a Java Application

Tags: java, jess

I am new with regards to jess. iam trying to run an example that is provide within the jess manual but i am failing. Can anyone help me with the steps on how to run the pricing engine example that is attached.

The example is refered too on page 85 within the manual http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/Jess71p2.pdf.

i have installed eclipse and have downloaded the files within the example folder. I do not know how to proceed in order to run the demo

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compile the Java files and then run `gov.sandia.jess.example.pricing.demo.Demo`. So, for example, on Mac or Linux, in the pricing_engine directory,

```
% javac -cp .:../../lib/jess.jar `find . -name '*.java'`
% java -cp .:../../lib/jess.jar gov.sandia.jess.example.pricing.demo.Demo
```

Comment: Hello Ernest, Thanks for the response. I am just running eclipse for the first time. how do i compile the java files? Do i compile them with eclipse? Do i have to copy them to a specific location? Kindly guide me on how i compile them within eclipse?

Comment: Providing a tutorial for Eclipse is beyond the format of Stack Overflow. Do you know how to compile and execute a set of Java classes from the command line - or are you new to Java, too?

Comment: i have managed to successfully compile some of the classes such as    
CatalogItem.java but i get errors when i compile the order.java class i get the error below; Order.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    private Customer customer;
            ^
  symbol:   class Customer
  location: class Order

Comment: @Patrick — it seems liken you’re trying to learn to embed Jess in Java without first having much in the way of Java experience. In particular, you need to learn about the “classpath.” The command lines in my answer show what the classpath needs to be to successfully compile this code. Show this question and my answer to a local Java expert and they’ll help you sort this out.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill thanks for the help so far. i have managed to compile all the classes but when i run the demo i get the error below even after setting the class path;  C:\Users\pkiwanuka\Documents\Work\Patrick_Project\Software\Jess71p2\examples\pricing_engine>java -cp .:..\..\lib\jess.jar gov.sandia.jess.example.pricing.demo.Demo
                                                                                                      Error: Could not find or load main class gov.sandia.jess.example.pricing.demo.Demo

Comment: Looks like that’s  my fault — I typoed pricing.demo for pricing_demo .

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill i have tried one with pricing_demo but i get the same error.       
C:\Users\pkiwanuka\Documents\Work\Patrick_Project\Software\Jess71p2\examples\pricing_engine>java -cp .:..\..\lib\jess.jar gov.sandia.jess.example.pricing_demo.Demo
Error: Could not find or load main class gov.sandia.jess.example.pricing_demo.Demo

Comment: Does Demo.class exist? Is it where it should be in the directory tree? Are you sure all the classes are compiled?